# Limiting 2 Digits Positive Numbers without any special character

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I want to restrict input from user to only 2 digit positive numbers. Also there should not be any space or special character be entered. Actually i want that a user can put %age rebate from 1 to 100 but he need not to give % sign. The code which i m trying is as given below:-

```js
$("#rebate").on("keyup change", function() {
  $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/\d{10}/ig, ''));
});
```

but this does not restrict either spaces, special characters and length more than 2. Kindly help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in the markup with an `input` field:

```
<input type="number" name="rebate" min="1" max="100">
```

Comment: But this allows +100 or any other digit starting with + sign. So that's why i need to figure out regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
\b(100|\d{2})\b
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qumK5x/1)

Explanation:

- wrapping `\b` (word boundaries) assures you match whole numbers, not parts of them
- first we check that there is `100` (that is allowed)
- if `100` does not match, we do to `\d{2}` that means "exactly two digits"
- both are connected with an alternative: `(...|...)`